# Why does my navigation bar disappear when I transition back to my home controller?

Tags: swift

I have a menu button embedded in my Navigation Bar which, takes me to the menu. But when I hit the back button on my menu page to come back to the original home page, the navigation bar has disappeared.

The problem showed up only after I used the following code to animate the transition between the 2 VCs:

@objc function for the menu button:

```
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromRight
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    present(menuVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

and @objc function for the backToHomePage button:

```
   let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = CATransitionType.push
    transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    present(menuVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

I get no errors, but the problem disappears if I use the navigation stack to push the menu control over, which I do not want to do.

Comment: "for the backToHomePage button" The problem is that you are not going "back". You are presenting `menuVC` again. The opposite of `present` is not another `present`; it is `dismiss`.

Comment: (More fundamentally, everything you are doing is wrong; you are transitioning to and from a view controller and trying to impose a custom animation as you do that, but what you are doing is not the way. You have to write a _custom transition animation_. There are strict procedures for doing that, and you are not following them.)